# How to parse json string in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

I needed to write a function with ajax  for rd-mailform, but the string is not parsed.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
"@EmailAuth": {
    rule: function(e) {
        email = e.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auth.php", // php return {"login":1,"status_":0,"user":null}
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            data: {
                "login": email
            },
            success: function(response) {

                --------------
                var res = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response.status_); // not work; why script stop?;
                --------------
                --------------
                var res = JSON.parse('{"login":1,"status_":0,"user":null}');
                console.log(response.status_); // work;  script running continue;
                --------------
            }
        });
        return Boolean(status)
    },
    message: "E-mail not found"
},
```

Comment: Well, try to log the response before the JSON.parse(). Also, do you get any errors?

Comment: If the server is putting a Content-Type header on the response of application/json, jQuery will have already parsed it with your method.  And trying to parse an already parsed object will error out.

Comment: success: function(response) {
    
               console.log(response); // return 
               {"login":1,"status":0,"user":null}

Comment: `console.log(typeof response)`

Comment: console.log(typeof response); //return string
response  = JSON.parse(response);                                                   
console.log(typeof response); //nothing return

Comment: auth.php: <?PHP
/* header('Content-Type: application/json'); */
echo json_encode(array("login"=>1, "status"=>0, "user"=>null));
 
?>

Comment: I tried this: var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); console.log(test); //return {"login":0,"status_":0"user":null}, but console.log(test.status_) //return undefined – Dmitriy 10 mins ago   Delete